# Get Sitecore content editor language selection

Tags: c#, controls, sitecore

I have created a custom Sitecore control (extending Control) to be used in the content editor. It calls a service and this services requires a language.

When the control is rendered it returns "en" as language every time, how can I get the user selection from the "language dropdown" in the content editor ?

In my method, I want to do something like this:

```
Language theLanguage = new Language.Parse("da-dk"); 
Item theLanguageSpecificItem = (Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master")).GetItem(myId, theLanguage);
```

However, I don't want the da-dk part to be hardcoded, I want to get it from the language dropdown in the content editor. For some reason I always get "en" if I use `Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.Current.Language`, Any idea ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, can you provide the code you currently have ? I didn't understand if one of your component is responsible for returning "en" each time, or if English is the default language of your whole application.

Comment: I can try :)

Ok, in my method I want to do something like this:

Language theLanguage = new Language.Parse("da-dk");
Item theLanguageSpecificItem = (Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master")).GetItem(myId, theLanguage);

However, I don't want the da-dk part the culture to be hardcoded, I want to get it from the language dropdown in the content editor. For some reason I always get "en" if I use Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.Current.Language 

Makes sense?

Comment: Are you looking for the `LanguageManager`? (`Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Sitecore.Context.Database)`) That would list all available languages. If you're trying to get a specific version (language) of an item, that's different.

Comment: No, not the language manager. The language selector in the top right corner when editing an item in the sitecore content editor. Sorry I can't post an image because this is my first post :(

Comment: So agnostic of the context language, you want a specific version of the item (in a target language)?

Comment: [link]http://postimg.org/image/7bd0y3jvd/

Comment: @nsgocev Tried that and it is set to "en", that's the problem.

Comment: @BradChristie Correct, a specific version. But because I always get "en" I want to get it from the language selector in the editor.

Comment: The available language list is accessible through `LanguageManager` (`sitecore/system/Languages`). If you're seeing what languages a specific item has available, you can check against `.item.Versions` (and therefore grab a specific item in a given language). But the dropdown you show is just a list of available languages (and shows if a translation exists).

Comment: @BradChristie Yes, I know how to check the version. Thank you for keep trying to understand :)
My control is running in the content editor and generates a dropdown based on some values returned by a service. This service requires the current culture used in sitecore, but for whatever reason it always returns english even if I select some other language. 

I have tried with `Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.Current.Language` and 
`LanguageManager.DefaultLanguage` and `Sitecore.Context.Language` but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, finally got it. When selecting another language you can request the language by simply doing like this.

`string currentLanguage = HttpContext.Current.Request["scLanguage"];`

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Awesome. And, FWIW, that language selector control is `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Languages.GalleryLanguagesForm, Sitecore.Client`. `Sitecore.Context.Language` is going to stay consistent because it controls the UI itself (otherwise your save and other actions would be translated). it may also be worth noting that the commands (`item:*` for example) appears to have a `language` parameter passed in through `ClientPipelineArgs` that may prove to be helpful (though a lot are generated by `CommandContext.Items[0].Language` internally).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Sitecore Context to get it?

```
Sitecore.Context.Culture.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected language is stored in a hidden field on the page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="scLanguage" name="scLanguage" value="en">
```

This changes when you change language, and is posted with each request.

```
string language = Sitecore.WebUtil.GetFormValue("scLanguage");
```

Internally this just does a `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[fieldName]`. If you are extending a control then you may already have access to the language as a property, or take a look at one of the existing Sitecore controls and follow their implementation pattern, e.g. `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.LookupEx`:

```
public string ItemLanguage
{
  get
  {
    return this.GetViewStateString("ItemLanguage");
  }
  set
  {
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) value, "value");
    this.SetViewStateString("ItemLanguage", value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but looks like you may be able to get the selected language in the content editor by parsing the language parameter of the ServerProperties.

```
Language.Parse(Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["language"] as string)
```

Comment: Don't think that will work... or it will probably give the english language like all the other things I tried.